# CSS nth-child: every 3rd element starting from the 4th

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to select every 3rd `section` tag but starting from the fourth. So the bold elements below would indicate those that I would like to select:

1. section
2. section
3. section
4. **section**
5. section
6. section
7. **section**
8. section
9. section

I've tried the following code but it doesn't appear to be working

```
section:nth-child(3n+1)
```

Comment: there is a good play to play with nth-child, https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/ also i recommend to use nth-of-type() instead of nth-child here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to start from the 4th element use `+4` not `+1`

```css
section:nth-child(3n+4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
<section>Section</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is :

`section:nth-child (3n+4)` instead of `section:nth-child(3n+1)`

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Panther_007/h9f8y4wh/)

Answer (score 4):

`section:nth-child(3n + 4)` or `section:nth-child(3n + 1):not(:first-child)`.

Here you have example: http://jsfiddle.net/rxtdrf13/2/